# Hiding sensitive data in VCR

Tags: ruby, rspec, vcr

In a recorded cassette from VCR gem I've got:

```
http_interactions:
- request:
    method: get
    uri: https://nme_site/rest/api/2/search?.a_lot_of_data
    body:
      encoding: US-ASCII
      string: ''
    headers:
      Accept:
      - application/json
      Accept-Encoding:
      - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
      User-Agent:
      - Ruby
      Authorization:
      - Basic ZGV345646543653
```

How to hide `Authorization: - Basic ZGV345646543653` ?

I was trying to:

`config.filter_sensitive_data('<AUTH>') { 'http_interactions.request.Authorization' }` but it won't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the docs on [`#filter_sensitive_data`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/vcr/VCR/Configuration:filter_sensitive_data), this should do it:

```rb
config.filter_sensitive_data('<AUTH>') { |interaction|
  interaction.request.headers['Authorization']
}
```

This will replace `Basic ZGV345646543653` with `<AUTH>`.

If you only want to replace `ZGV345646543653` so the header reads `Basic <AUTH>`, then you'd need this:

```rb
config.filter_sensitive_data('<AUTH>') { |interaction|
  interaction.request.headers['Authorization'].sub('Basic ', '')
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, still received those values

Comment: `interaction.request.headers['Authorization']` returns an `Array`, not `String`, so you need to do `interaction.request.headers['Authorization'][0]`.